# Tomcat 9 Valve Causing Server Start Failure

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, tomcat-valve

I have written a custom tomcat valve to parse HTTP headers and use them to authenticate. The valve works by extending AuthenticatorBase. I compiled it and placed it in $CATALINA_HOME/lib. Here is code:

```java
    public class TomcatLogin extends AuthenticatorBase {

        private String[] roleNames = null;
        private String ivcreds = null;
        private String ivuser = null;
        private String ivgroups = null;
        private GenericPrincipal principal = null;

        // Constructor defers to super class (Authenticator base)
        public TomcatLogin(){
            super();
        }

        protected boolean doAuthenticate(Request request, HttpServletResponse response)
        {
            List<String> groupsList = null;

            System.out.println("Obtaining Headers from Request");
            try {
                ivuser = request.getHeader("iv-user");
                ivcreds = request.getHeader("iv-creds");
                ivgroups = request.getHeader("iv-groups");
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Require all header credentials for proper authentication
            if(ivuser == null || ivcreds == null || ivgroups == null)
                return false;

            // Split ivgroups by comma seporated value
            // Then remove head and tail quotation marks
            roleNames = ivgroups.split(",");
            for(int i=0; i<roleNames.length; i++){
                roleNames[i] = roleNames[i].substring(1, roleNames[i].length()-1 );
                groupsList.add(roleNames[i]);
            }

            principal = new GenericPrincipal(ivuser, ivcreds, groupsList);
            request.setUserPrincipal(principal);

            return true;
        }

        public String getAuthMethod() {
            return "HTTPAuthenticator";
        }

    }
```

I then tell Tomcat to use the valve in the server.xml. The [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.html) for extending AuthenticatorBase says **When this class is utilized, the Context to which it is attached (or a parent Container in a hierarchy) must have an associated Realm that can be used for authenticating users and enumerating the roles to which they have been assigned**. I  thought I had configured it correctly, but it throws and error and Tomcat fails to start. Here is the `server.xml` config:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    ...
      <Server>
        <Service name="Catalina">
          <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
              <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" 
                     resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
            </Realm>

            <!-- Here is my valve -->
            <Valve className="package.of.my.custom.valve.TomcatLogin" />

            <Host ... >
               ...
            </Host>
          </Engine>
        </Service>
      </Server>
```

And here is the Error message I am getting:

```
10-Jan-2019 10:11:03.576 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement End event threw exception
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
... A bunch of useless stacktrace
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Configuration error:  Must be attached to a Context at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.setContainer(AuthenticatorBase.java:278)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.addValve(StandardPipeline.java:335)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addValve(ContainerBase.java:1133)
    ... 27 more

10-Jan-2019 10:11:03.579 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (107, 82) : Configuration error:  Must be attached to a Context
10-Jan-2019 10:11:03.579 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

I think my valve is written correctly, so my guess is that the issue is in the configuration. Not sure why it is not getting a context to attach to. Any ideas?

**Edit:**
I tried putting the valve in my app's `META-INF/context.xml` (I had to make one since there wasn't one to begin with). Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Context>
    <Valve className="package.of.my.custom.valve.TomcatLogin" />
</Context>
```

The server then start, but it fails to deploy any of the applications. I am getting similar error to an IBM valve which I originally tried to use over this custom implementation where it cannot find the `AuthenticatorBase` class from `catalina.jar`. Here are the `SEVERE` errors I am getting:

```
    10-Jan-2019 15:34:06.673 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sample-DB]]
...
Stacktrace info
...
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startDocument(Digester.java:1102)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.nio.charset.Charset.put(Charset.java:538)
...
Stacktrace
...
    10-Jan-2019 15:34:06.688 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/fmac/deploy/sample.war] has finished in [11] ms
    10-Jan-2019 15:34:06.689 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/fmac/deploy/sample-auth.war]
    10-Jan-2019 15:34:06.692 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement Begin event threw error
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase
...
Stacktrace
The Error Below is the most confusing one. How can it not find this class?
...
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
...
Stacktrace
...
    10-Jan-2019 15:34:13.823 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-3] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error processing request
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.B2CConverter
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.convertURI(CoyoteAdapter.java:1072)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was finally able to find out what the issues were. We have a custom tomcat implementation, part of which involves appending the classpath in the `java` command. For some reason, some of the database drivers that were being used caused the Tomcat to fail to find any of the libraries in `CATALINA_HOME/lib`. I'm running inside a Docker container and this was some old vestigial stuff from a VM version. We ended up just having to toss those 
drivers out.

Not really sure why they would completely override the base `lib/` directory, but at least these errors when away and I was actually able to use the pre-built authenticator I had instead of fine tuning this custom one.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `<Valve>` inside of your `<Context>` element. That should usually be within a `META-INF/context.xml` file in your web application and not in `conf/server.xml`.

Comment: When I do that, the server start but I get some other errors causing all my apps (including those not using a context.xml or security-constraints in web.xml) to not work. I've posted a deeper explanation above